# How to convert existing AWS environment into infra as code?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, terraform, aws-opsworks

When we were building our AWS account,  we did not think about using cloud formation or terraform. Now we have our environmemt all setup but don't want to tear down everything and build using cloud formation or terraform. So is there a way we can get our infrastructure to be imported and managed through one of them?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Terraform supports import, but that only supports the present state into state file. You still need to write the code. Cloudformation does not support import.

Something like https://github.com/dtan4/terraforming can be of help but YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for letting me discover terraforming!

Comment: @AnshuPrateek Sorry for the late response. I have tried importing the exisiting infrastructure via terraform import command but how do I exactly have everything written into main.tf and have the infra managed through one file?

Comment: import will only add it to your state file. To generate the main.tf , you need to use terraforming.

Comment: +1 for terraforming : ) very neat tool, and I agree YMMV, and yes, TF doc is here they say they will in the future: https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html

Answer (score 1):

A pretty complete answer could be found at [AWS Export configuration as cloudformation template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55764927/2033312), which also covers Terraform for this purpose.

#### TL;DR

AWS Import/Export configuration as code (CloudFormationn | Terraform).

Based on our Infrastructure as Code (IaC) experience we found several ways to translate existing manually deployed (from Web Console UI) AWS infra to Cloudformation (CF) and / or Terraform (TF) code. Posible solutions are listed below:

**AWS Cloudformation Templates**

- CF-1 | [AWS CloudFormation native import feature](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-import-existing-resources-into-a-cloudformation-stack/)
- CF-2 | aws cli & manually translate to CF
- CF-3 | [Former2](https://former2.com)
- CF-4 | [AWS CloudFormer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html)

**Terraform Code / Modules**

- TF-1 | [Terraforming](https://github.com/dtan4/terraforming)
- TF-2 | [CloudCraft](https://cloudcraft.co/) + [Modules.tf](https://modules.tf/)

---

**Related Article:** https://medium.com/@exequiel.barrirero/aws-export-configuration-as-code-cloudformation-terraform-b1bca8949bca

Answer (score 0):

As per October 2019, AWS supports importing legacy resources into CloudFormation. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html for examples.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking to import your existing AWS Infrastructure into Terraform, you can give a try to a tool that we recently launched - https://www.kapstan.io/generate-terraform