# Is there a way to generate a CloudFormation template from current resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have implemented a project on my personal account & I need to implement the same solution on my work account. Is there a way to generate a cloud formation template for the whole project so I can just upload the template on my work account?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a cloud formation template from an existing AWS environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55391398/how-to-create-a-cloud-formation-template-from-an-existing-aws-environment)

Comment: You may find that some of the automated solutions take quite a bit of work.  Doing it manually takes a while but isn't terrible for a handful of resources.  Not sure how many resources you're tackling though.

Comment: How did it go? Still not clear  what you can do?

Answer (score 1):

A popular choice is [former2](https://former2.com/) which is **open sourced** and developed by [AWS Hero](https://aws.amazon.com/developer/community/heroes/ian-mckay/).