# How to generate AWS CloudFormation using existing environments

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-cli

I have existing AWS configuration

- Api getway
- RDS
- EBS
- EC2
- Cognito
- S3
- aws Lambda

Now I want to create different environment like Dev, QA, UAT and Prod

Is there any option available in AWS or Open source to generate cloud formation scripts with existing configurations?

Comment: I am also want feature for our project.

Comment: another alternative: https://github.com/iann0036/former2

Comment: Related discussion: [AWS Export configuration as cloudformation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057526/aws-export-configuration-as-cloudformation-template)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at [CloudFormer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html).

> CloudFormer is a template creation beta tool that creates an AWS CloudFormation template from existing AWS resources in your account. You select any supported AWS resources that are running in your account, and CloudFormer creates a template in an Amazon S3 bucket.

Not all resources are supported but you can use it as a starting point and improve the generated template manually afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

**[CloudFormer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html)** is currently in beta. We recommend against utilizing it in critical or production environments. -- by AWS documentation